Ajax Pagination 404 not found in Wordpress
I create a theme and want to make ajax pagination for my blog page. Actually, from page 1 to 5 its working normally. But why from page 6 to the end of pagination, have 404 not found? If you think, "maybe there is no page 6?", but actually there is page 6, but I don't understand why not loaded. This is my index.php file:
<?php 
get_header();
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-12">
            <div id="postAjax">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php
                    $paged = max(1, get_query_var('paged', 1));
                    $query_posts = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'posts_per_page' => 6,
                        'paged' => $paged
                    ));

                    if ($query_posts->have_posts()) {
                        while ($query_posts->have_posts()) : $query_posts->the_post();
                            ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                                <article <?php post_class();?>>
                                    <div class="card h-100" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <div style="height: 200px; overflow: hidden; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);">
                                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'medium', array('class' => 'card-img-top', 'style' => 'object-fit: cover;')); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <h2 class="card-title h5"><a class="text-decoration-none" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        endwhile;
                        ?>
                        <div id="paginationAjax" class="my-4">
                            <?php
                            $big = 999999999; // Angka besar untuk memastikan paginasi berfungsi
                            echo paginate_links(array(
                                'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                                'format' => 'page/%#%/',
                                'current' => $paged,
                                'total' => $query_posts->max_num_pages
                            ));
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        ?><p>Tidak ada yang dapat ditampilkan</p><?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#postAjax').on('click', '#paginationAjax a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            
            // Placeholder HTML
            var placeholderHtml = 
                '<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">' +
                    '<article class="card h-100" style="width: 100%;">' +
                        '<div style="height: 200px; overflow: hidden; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);">' +
                            '<div class="placeholder-glow">' +
                                '<div class="placeholder card-img-top" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="card-body">' +
                            '<h2 class="card-title h5 placeholder-glow">' +
                                '<span class="placeholder col-6"></span>' +
                            '</h2>' +
                            '<p class="card-text placeholder-glow">' +
                                '<span class="placeholder col-7"></span>' +
                                '<span class="placeholder col-4"></span>' +
                                '<span class="placeholder col-4"></span>' +
                                '<span class="placeholder col-6"></span>' +
                                '<span class="placeholder col-8"></span>' +
                            '</p>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</article>' +
                '</div>';

            // Show placeholders
            $('#postAjax .row').html(placeholderHtml.repeat(6));

            // Load new content
            $('#postAjax').load(link + ' #postAjax > *', function(response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

the pagination work until the end
